# Make every word on a webpage clickable, with a popup

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do what the title states.  I want to have a page with words, and have every word clickable.  When a word is clicked, I want a popup above the text to show up until the next word is clicked.

The way I plan to do this now is to have each word in a span with its own id, and have javascript show / hide the popups on click.  I wonder if there is a more efficient way than giving each word its own span, since there may be hundreds of words.  Are there any more efficient alternatives to my idea?

Comment: Do the popups contain HTML, or is it plaintext?  Wondering if you could simply use `title=""` or `<abbr>`

Comment: What text will be inside the pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your project is about, but I propose to use the `title` attribute, and alter it with a jQuery plugin like Tipsy.

Tipsy is a lightweight plugin, you can set the trigger (default is hover) to click, so if you click on an element, the text you set in the `title` attribute will be shown. You are also allowed to set the direction of the tooltip (default is s stands for south, where it will be appear top of the word) and use custom CSS to redesign it. Check the documentation here: [jQuery Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).